# image background opacity with no affecting borders

Tags: html, css, sass

How to set background with opacity without affecting border line opacity? Solutions I found does not help.

```
<div class="selected">
 <img
 src="../assets/img/image-product-1-thumbnail.jpg"
 alt="product-1-thumbnail"
 />
</div>
```

```
img {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 5rem;
 height: auto;
 border-radius: 10%;
}

.selected {
    background-color: red;
    img {
        border: 2px solid red;
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let thumbnailImages = document.querySelectorAll('.thumbnail');

thumbnailImages.forEach(image => {
     
    image.addEventListener("mouseover", ()=> {
          image.classList.add('blur')
          image.parentElement.style.outline = "2px solid hsl(26, 100%, 55%)";
          image.parentElement.style.borderRadius = "12px";    
    })
    image.addEventListener("mouseout", ()=> {
          image.classList.remove('blur')
          image.parentElement.style.outline = "";
    })
});
```

```css
.left-section-bottom{
    display: flex;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 32px auto;
    gap: 40px;
}
.left-section-bottom img{
    border-radius: 12px;
}
.thumbnail.blur{
   opacity: 0.4;
   cursor: pointer;
}
.thumbnail-div{
   display: flex;
}
```

```html
            <div class="left-section-bottom">
                <div class="thumbnail-div"><img class="thumbnail" src="images/image-product-1-thumbnail.jpg" alt=""></div>
                <div class="thumbnail-div"><img class="thumbnail" src="images/image-product-1-thumbnail.jpg" alt=""></div>
                <div class="thumbnail-div"><img class="thumbnail" src="images/image-product-1-thumbnail.jpg" alt=""></div>
                <div class="thumbnail-div"><img class="thumbnail" src="images/image-product-1-thumbnail.jpg" alt=""></div>
            </div>
```

I was looking for an answer to this same question, and finally figured it out. The original question is in regard to this challenge:
https://www.frontendmentor.io/challenges/ecommerce-product-page-UPsZ9MJp6

Since there are 4 images you have to loop through them one by one.
You have to use querySelectorAll, not querySelector.

Just loop through your thumbnail images with a forEach().

Wrap your images in a div (as Kingsly mentioned) so you can apply
border style to the div instead of your blurred images.

This code should work if you add your images.

Answer (score 1):

You should put the image in a `div` container with the size you want. Add the `border` and `border-radius` to the div, add `opacity` to the `img` element.

IMAGE CREDIT: https://www.pexels.com/@belle-co-99483

```css
.img-container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 10%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: .7;
}

.selected {
    //background-color: red;
}
img {
}
```

```html
<div class="selected">
<div class="img-container">
   <img
   src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1000445/pexels-photo-1000445.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940"
   alt="product-1-thumbnail"
   />
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But if I put ```img { opacity: .7 }``` then all images are the same opacity. I want to have only one which is selected. How to do it?

Comment: Maybe you should create an `opacity` class, remove the opacity from the image style. Check with `if statement` the selected image an add the opacity class ( you can still use inline style ) to it.